# ASP.NET/WebAPI: $.ajax has 404 and $.getJSON has Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm working on a ASP.NET web API with a C# project that I try to call from JavaScript.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function LoadGraph() {
var file = document.getElementById("file-datas");
if ('files' in file)
{
    if (file.files.length == 0) {
        Console.log("Empty file");
    } else {
        var text = file.files;
        /*$.ajax({
            url: "api/Graph",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: $(text).serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        })*/

        //$.getJSON('api/Graph', file, function (data) { console.log(data) });
    }
}
```

And here is my Controller:

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/Graph")]

public class GraphController : ApiController
{
    // POST: api/Graph
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("All", Name = "LoadGraph")]
    public IHttpActionResult LoadGraph(string text)
    {
        RecursiveGraph result = test.SecondMethodFruchterman(text);
        return Ok(result.name);
    }
}
```

As you see I tried two methods in my JavaScript:

- The first one with $.ajax makes `POST http://localhost:53497/Home/api/Graph 404 (Not Found)`.
- The second one with $.getJSON makes `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

result.name is a string but I want to transfer result itself after solving these problems and getting something that works.

- I don't know which one of the two method is better to use.
- I don't know why I get a 404 error on $.ajax and no on $.getJSON.
- And I don't know why I get this Max call stack error since it seems to appear when recursive functions are called and it's not the case here.

Comment: Does your controller action `LoadGraph` ever get called?

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understood your question but I never call LoadGraph without with jquery

Comment: Yes I want to know weather your `LoadGraph` method get called from your ajax post method? You can check that by set a breackpoint in your `LoadGraph` method

Comment: I don't really know how breakpoints work in web, I add one at the first line of LoadGraph and in my browser's console and nothing changed.

Comment: Please try out the code in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the corrected code

```
//[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/Graph")]
public class GraphController : ApiController
{
    // POST: api/Graph
    [Route("LoadGraph", Name = "LoadGraph")]
    public IHttpActionResult LoadGraph([FromBody] string text)
    {
        RecursiveGraph result = test.SecondMethodFruchterman(text);
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

I need to add [FromBody] because string is not a model.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that the resolved URL is `POST http://localhost:53497/Home/api/Graph 404 (Not Found)` which is wrong since your URL is actually supposed to be `http://localhost:53497/api/Graph`. To fix, prepend your AJAX urls with a `/`.

The second problem is likely the server error being returned as text to your web client. It is probably due to your recursion never terminating. I can't see that code in detail, but `RecursiveGraph result` tips me off. I'd bet on your recursive method never terminating, which would definitely max out the callstack.

Comment: Hello, I may be didn't give you enough details. For the first problem I tried many things including prepend with a / and I get `POST http://localhost:53497/api/Graph 404 (Not Found)`. Concerning the second problem I tried to send a string instead a recursivegraph and it does the same thing with a stupid exemple: `public IHttpActionResult LoadGraph(string text)
        {
            RecursiveGraph result = test.SecondMethodFruchterman(text);
            string testresult = test.Test("a");
            return Ok(testresult);
        }` with Test which returns "b"

Comment: @elpha01 repeat test for second test, commenting out the `RecursiveGraph` line which is likely your problem. Regarding first your route is probably set up for `GET` only - you can specify via route attributes things like `HttpGet`, `HttpPost` etc.

Comment: `// POST: api/Graph
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("All", Name = "LoadGraph")]
        public IHttpActionResult LoadGraph(string text)
        {
            //RecursiveGraph result = test.SecondMethodFruchterman(text);
            string testresult = test.Test("a");
            return Ok(testresult);
        }` I made a mistake while copying my code, here how it is recompiled and the page refreshed. I still have the same problem.

Comment: @elpha01 stop using your classes. Have the action method only do `return "a"` and see what happens. No `test.` anything, no `result` object.

Comment: I don't know why and since when but now I always have the error `GET http://localhost:53497/api/Graph 404 (Not Found)` with`$.getJSON('/api/Graph', "ff", function (data) { console.log(data) });` and `// POST: api/Graph
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("All", Name = "LoadGraph")]
        public IHttpActionResult LoadGraph(string text)
        {
            return Ok("a");
            //RecursiveGraph result = test.SecondMethodFruchterman(text);
            //return Ok(result);
        }` Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shall change your `ajax` call to this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("LoadGraph", "Graph")',
    type: "POST",
    traditional: true,
    data: {
        text: $(text).serialize()
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
   }
})
```

You get the 404 (not found error code) because your ajax post url `api/Graph` is just your referring to your controller

Why did you even change your controller RoutePrefix to "api/Graph"? Is there a special reason for doing this?

Comment: Same 404 problem. I added the RoutePrefix because I used an exemple which I get from a friend and he used it.

Comment: So then it is useless and doesn't help you in any way. Can you remove the `RoutePrefix` part in your Controller and try my updated code

Comment: got this `POST http://localhost:53497/Home/@Url.Action(%22LoadGraph%22,%20%22Graph%22) 404 (Not Found)` Thank you gain for helping me

Comment: My friend solved it, I have to use [FromBody] on my string parameter because it's not a model.